# R: Deleting observations (rows) within a variable (column)

Tags: r

I can only seem to find codes that delete observations from the complete data-frame. 
However, I only want to delete certain observations from a certain variable.

Example: Would you recommend our services to friends & family?

```
     1 Yes
     2 No
     8 Don't know
     9 Refuse
```

How can I delete 8 and 9 out of this variable?

Thanks again!

Comment: Could you please paste your data into the question using `dput(your_data_frame)`. This will make it easier to answer your question. The aim is to provide a reproducible example [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

#removing what you do not want
  df |> 
    filter(!ans %in% c("Don't know", "Refuse"))

#keeping what you do want
  df |> 
  filter(ans == "Yes" | ans == "No" )
```

in base R one option of many might be:

```
  df[!df$ans %in% c("Don't know", "Refuse"), ]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 8, 9),
                 ans = c("Yes", "No", "Don't know", "Refuse"))
```